ETH tokens with no value needing 5k to transfer to coins
I have 15.54 ETH tokens in my Atomic wallet but their value shows as 0 (zero)
I have been told that to turn them into coins with value I need to deposit 10% of their value into my wallet before I can extract them for currency via my swyftx
Would this be normal, because I would expect the gas figure to transfer them to my swyftx wallet would be about $20.
